# keywords calling in robot framework for our own java library

Tags: java, robotframework

i want to write my own keywords java library and call them in my testcases.
i tried in many ways but not found any correct solution.
Even the robot framework documentation is not clear for java based libraries.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Venkat.

Comment: Please elaborate your question. You should explain your issue in detail and provide infos about your case, and what you tried so far.

Comment: I recommend creating the smallest possible keyword in java, then show us what you have done to incorporate that library into robot. Also, please describe what "not found any correct solution" means. Does it silently fail? Do you get errors? is the wrong keyword called? Is it called with the wrong parameters? Does it not seem to return the correct result?

Comment: public class MyKeywords {

 public String sayHi(String name)
 {
  return "Hello " +name ;
 }

 public String sayHi()
 {
  return "Hello World!";
 }

 public String typeOf(Object param)
 {
  return param.getClass().getSimpleName();
 }
}

Comment: Above is the smallest java code for keywords calling in robot framework.      I am using robotframework-3.0.2, and i have installed ride along with python 2.7 and jython 2.5. I have also installed and using java. i am getting import error while importing this java file in RIDE.

Comment: I have also tried using spec file generation by entering the below commands                                                                                                                                                       CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/jvm/sun-java-6/lib/tools.jar:myjavalib-0.1.jar jython -m robot.libdoc MyJavaLibrary MyJavaLibrarySpec.xml                                 But spec file is not generating using the above commands

Comment: @venkat I have the same question, did you find a solution

Comment: not yet @mosaad

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried through command line?
The following steps might help you:
1) Create java file, compile it to java class
2) In Test Suite, Import Library as fully qualified name, e.g. if java file which you have made reside under package (not default)
Library  packganame/javafilenamewithoutextension
3) add java class into classpath
4 ) run jybot command
You need to run jybot (robot installed in jython) command to extend robot framework using java.